# Avoiding circular dependencies in game unit targeting

Tags: design-patterns, uml

I was working on the uml for a game I'm currently developing and got a bit stuck thinking about how to do Unit targeting.

So to explain, currently I have a UnitManager class that has a list of Units which it updates once every frame.

I want some of the units to be able to target one of the other units if it is within a certain distance. To do this I imagine I need to get a reference to the other units in the UnitManager list and check which of them are in range in some 
way.

**Question:** How can a Unit target another Unit without having a circular dependency between Unit and UnitManager (or anywhere else)?

Thanks in advance, Vidar.

**Edit:** Some UML examples:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should show (the relevant parts of) your UML as a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Having a bi-derectional relation is ofcourse a circular dependency, but a very special case of, which can be acceptabel when regarding it accordingly. All other circular dependencies should be omit, if possible (what is not always the case, then they need even more regards, especially when maintaining such a system).

To break circular depdencies there are several default techniques available. One that works mostly is to pull out the interface part and make the dependencies from the implementations only to interfaces instead of cocnrete classes. This gives also several other benefits like improved re-use, extensibility, or testability.

In the concrete case here, I woudl refer to the Observer Pattern proposed as part of the classical GoF patterns. There you have an (abstract) observer class, which would be your Unit, which implements a method that is called to notify the update. And there is a subject class, which would be your UnitManager class. The UnitManager class only knows, i.e., depends on, the abstract observer class or interface and not on the concrete ones. And each unit class that might trigger an update of all other unit instances will have a dependency to the UnitManger (or when being consequent to an abstract super class or interface of it).

When you further want to deal with the nearness, it strongly depends how the remaining logis is and how it is implemented. A basic solution would be registering and de-registering the units according to their distance. An other option is that the UnitManager only call the registered observers that are close enough.

Answer (score 0):

Basically circular references are not bad. They just might need extra attention.

You are asking a design question here which is definitely opinion based. However, I guess there should be a supervising instance (e.g. the `UnitManager`) which has oversight and can manage distances between `Unit`s. So it's probably a good idea to have the methods implemented here which can tell about "nearness" of `Unit`s.